# is it possible to change git commit date to an arbitrary date which is too far?

Tags: git

I know about `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` and all methods that help us to change a git commit date and for example I want to change last commit date by below command:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2019-01-01 22:01:02 +0000" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "2019-01-01 22:01:02 +0000"
```

since I am working in an international company I need to commit changes in Persian(Jalali) Date format so I need to use 1398 as a year number for committing changes (not 2019!) but it seems that GIT doesn't accept a date which is too far

Comment: " I need to use 1398 as a year number for committing changes (not 2019!) " - this is *not* a reason to change a commit date. Date+times in computers (and Git specifically) are internally stored as Unix timestamps which are UTC values and not in the Gregorian date format. If the company is incorrectly representing Hebrew years in Unix timestamps then there's a LOT of things which will go wrong and you should everything you can to stop them doing that.

Comment: I believe the git command-line tools will use whatever your system default Calendar is - so just change your system to use the Hebrew calendar and your `git log` and other commands will show you the year as 1398, and so on. This is the case on Windows, Linux, macOS, etc.

Comment: I changed my system date and unfortunately, it doesn't work for me @Dai

Comment: Don't change your system date, I said change your system calendar settings.

Comment: I just typed it wrong, I changed my "system calendar settings" $Dai

Answer (score 0):

Git, like many other Unix programs, stores dates as a Unix timestamp, which is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 at midnight UTC. All of these timestamps are specified using the Gregorian calendar, and since Git is only designed to parse timestamps that are in the Gregorian calendar, trying to provide a year number of 1398 will not have the behavior you expect: Git will think you are trying to provide a Gregorian year of 1398 CE. Any other tools, such as a Git hosting server, will think the same thing.

Moreover, on 32-bit systems, the time is stored as a 32-bit integer, which means that the range of valid timestamps includes only the Gregorian years 1902–2038 CE. If you're using a 32-bit version of Git, it will not even be capable of expressing the year 1398 (which, again, it views as 621 years ago). Most Unix systems are 64-bit these days, but many Windows users are still using 32-bit software, which may be why your Git version isn't capable of handling that date.

As unfortunate as it is to say, there isn't a good way to make Git produce non-Gregorian output or handle non-Gregorian input. It's designed to handle timestamps in the way Unix does, which is very closely tied in with the Gregorian calendar. It's possible you can use the `%x %X` format in places you'd like to see the date and time, and on your system it may produce a localized calendar, but it also may not.

Comment: unfortunately you right and there is no "good way" for this, but I think there are dirty methods...